# High Availability for ISR 4431 IPSec VPNs

Tags: vpn, ospf, ipsec, redundancy, hsrp

I have the following lab setup in GNS3.  R1 & R2 are VPN endpoint at my datacenters and R3 is simulating a remote site.  What i'm trying to accomplish is having one tunnel from R3 to the datacenter that leverages both R1 & R2 using HSRP and stateful failover.  The configurations I'm attaching work, however the failover time is slow (30 sec+) and also fails when normalizing the solution.  Would there be some timers I can adjust or perhaps leverage something else to speed up this process?  Or would it just be best to scrap the HSRP solution and use two tunnels and let OSPF failover?

[image]

Here is a picture of what happens when shutdown r1 to test.

[image]

R1:

```
!
hostname r1
!
ipc zone default
 association 1
  no shutdown
  protocol sctp
   local-port 5000
    local-ip 172.16.1.2
   remote-port 5000
    remote-ip 172.16.1.3
!
redundancy inter-device
 scheme standby HA-Out
 security ipsec TUNNEL-PROFILE-SITE
!
redundancy
!
crypto ikev2 proposal IKEv2-PROPOSAL
 encryption aes-gcm-256
 prf sha384
 group 20
!
crypto ikev2 policy IKEv2-POLICY
 match fvrf any
 proposal IKEv2-PROPOSAL
!
crypto ikev2 keyring IKEv2-KEYRING
 peer TO-SITE
  address 172.16.2.1
  pre-shared-key cisco123
 !
!
crypto ikev2 profile IKEv2-PROFILE-SITE
 match identity remote any
 authentication local pre-share
 authentication remote pre-share
 keyring local IKEv2-KEYRING
!
crypto ipsec transform-set MYSET esp-gcm 256
 mode tunnel
!
crypto ipsec profile TUNNEL-PROFILE-SITE
 set transform-set MYSET
 set ikev2-profile IKEv2-PROFILE-SITE
 redundancy HA-Out stateful
!
interface Loopback0
 ip address 10.1.1.1 255.255.255.255
!
interface Tunnel208
 description <== Datacenter Connection to SITE ==>
 ip unnumbered Loopback0
 tunnel source 172.16.1.1
 tunnel mode ipsec ipv4
 tunnel destination 172.16.2.1
 tunnel protection ipsec profile TUNNEL-PROFILE-SITE
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0
 ip address 172.16.1.2 255.255.255.240
 standby 1 ip 172.16.1.1
 standby 1 priority 110
 standby 1 preempt
 standby 1 name HA-Out
 duplex auto
 speed auto
 media-type rj45
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
 ip address 10.1.200.2 255.255.255.0
 standby 0 name HA-In
 standby 1 ip 10.1.200.1
 standby 1 priority 110
 standby 1 preempt
 duplex auto
 speed auto
 media-type rj45
 !
router ospf 1
 passive-interface default
 no passive-interface Tunnel208
 network 10.1.1.1 0.0.0.0 area 0
 network 10.1.200.0 0.0.0.255 area 0
 network 10.254.2.32 0.0.0.3 area 0
!
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 172.16.1.10
!
```

R2:

```
!
hostname r2
!
ipc zone default
 association 1
  no shutdown
  protocol sctp
   local-port 5000
    local-ip 172.16.1.3
   remote-port 5000
    remote-ip 172.16.1.2
!
redundancy inter-device
 scheme standby HA-Out
 security ipsec TUNNEL-PROFILE-SITE
!
redundancy
!
crypto ikev2 proposal IKEv2-PROPOSAL
 encryption aes-gcm-256
 prf sha384
 group 20
!
crypto ikev2 policy IKEv2-POLICY
 match fvrf any
 proposal IKEv2-PROPOSAL
!
crypto ikev2 keyring IKEv2-KEYRING
 peer TO-SITE
  address 172.16.2.1
  pre-shared-key cisco123
 !
!
crypto ikev2 profile IKEv2-PROFILE-SITE
 match identity remote any
 authentication local pre-share
 authentication remote pre-share
 keyring local IKEv2-KEYRING
!
crypto ipsec transform-set MYSET esp-gcm 256
 mode tunnel
!
crypto ipsec profile TUNNEL-PROFILE-SITE
 set transform-set MYSET
 set ikev2-profile IKEv2-PROFILE-SITE
 redundancy HA-Out stateful
!
interface Loopback0
 ip address 10.1.1.2 255.255.255.255
!
interface Tunnel208
 description <== Datacenter Connection to SITE ==>
 ip unnumbered Loopback0
 tunnel source 172.16.1.1
 tunnel mode ipsec ipv4
 tunnel destination 172.16.2.1
 tunnel protection ipsec profile TUNNEL-PROFILE-SITE
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0
 ip address 172.16.1.3 255.255.255.240
 standby 1 ip 172.16.1.1
 standby 1 priority 105
 standby 1 name HA-Out
 duplex auto
 speed auto
 media-type rj45
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
 ip address 10.1.200.3 255.255.255.0
 standby 0 name HA-In
 standby 1 ip 10.1.200.1
 standby 1 priority 105
 duplex auto
 speed auto
 media-type rj45
!
router ospf 1
 passive-interface default
 no passive-interface Tunnel208
 network 10.1.1.2 0.0.0.0 area 0
 network 10.1.200.0 0.0.0.255 area 0
 network 10.254.2.32 0.0.0.3 area 0
!
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 172.16.1.10
!
```

R3:

```
!
hostname r3
!
crypto ikev2 proposal IKEv2-PROPOSAL
 encryption aes-gcm-256
 prf sha384
 group 20
!
crypto ikev2 policy IKEv2-POLICY
 match fvrf any
 proposal IKEv2-PROPOSAL
!
crypto ikev2 keyring IKEv2-KEYRING
 peer TO-DC01
  address 172.16.1.1
  pre-shared-key cisco123
 !
!
crypto ikev2 profile IKEv2-PROFILE-DC01
 match identity remote any
 authentication local pre-share
 authentication remote pre-share
 keyring local IKEv2-KEYRING
!
crypto ipsec transform-set MYSET esp-gcm 256
 mode tunnel
!
crypto ipsec profile TUNNEL-PROFILE-DC01
 set transform-set MYSET
 set ikev2-profile IKEv2-PROFILE-DC01
!
interface Loopback0
 ip address 10.10.1.1 255.255.255.255
!
interface Tunnel208
 description <== Datacenter Connection ==>
 ip unnumbered Loopback0
 tunnel source 172.16.2.1
 tunnel mode ipsec ipv4
 tunnel destination 172.16.1.1
 tunnel protection ipsec profile TUNNEL-PROFILE-DC01
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0
 ip address 172.16.2.1 255.255.255.240
 duplex auto
 speed auto
 media-type rj45
 bfd template sample
 no cdp enable
!
!
router ospf 1
 passive-interface default
 no passive-interface Tunnel208
 network 10.10.1.1 0.0.0.0 area 0
 network 10.254.2.32 0.0.0.3 area 0
!
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 172.16.2.10
!
```

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

> Would there be some timers I can adjust or perhaps leverage something
>   else to speed up this process? Or would it just be best to scrap the HSRP solution and use two tunnels and let OSPF failover?

Yes, there are HSRP timers that you can adjust, and you could use sub-second timers, but that will drive up the CPU utilization to possibly unacceptable levels. Cisco has a lot of documents describing HSRP features and configurations:

> ### HSRP Timers
>
> Each router only uses three timers in HSRP. The timers time hello
>   messages. The HSRP converges, when a failure occurs, depend on how the
>   HSRP hello and hold timers are configured. By default, these timers
>   are set to 3 and 10 seconds, respectively, which means that a hello
>   packet is sent between the HSRP standby group devices every 3 seconds,
>   and the standby device becomes active when a hello packet has not been
>   received for 10 seconds. You can lower these timer settings to speed
>   up the failover or preemption, but, to avoid increased CPU usage and
>   unnecessary standby state flapping, do not set the hello timer below
>   one (1) second or the hold timer below 4 seconds. Note that, if you
>   use the HSRP tracking mechanism and the tracked link fails, the
>   failover or preemption occurs immediately, regardless of the hello and
>   hold timers. When a timer expires, the router transitions to a new
>   HSRP state. The timers can be changed with this command: **standby
>   [***group-number***] timers** *hellotime holdtime*. For example,
>   **standby 1 timers 5 15**.

A routing protocol can failover much faster than HSRP. The idea of a FHRP like HSRP is that hosts usually only have a single default gateway, and the FHRP will create a virtual gateway to which the hosts on a LAN can send traffic destined for a different network. The routers will communicate with each other to determine which is the active router for the virtual gateway, and to see if the active router is still functioning. The standby router will take over if the active router fails, but the determination of failure of the active router takes time. It also takes time for a routing protocol to determine a path failure and reroute; you will never get instantaneous failover between separate devices.

---

There are also other things you would want to do for a true HA scenario. For example, you should have a link between R1 and R2, and you should track the router interfaces to SW1, decrementing the HSRP priority when the link fails but the router is still up.

Personally, I would set your layer-3 switch, AS01, as the gateway, then use a routing protocol between it and the two routers (with a link between the two routers) to let the routing protocol determine how to route the traffic.

Comment: We're using `standby 0 timers msec 250 msec 750` and yes it uses extra CPU.

Comment: HSRP could be a potential part of the solution, but I know there are timers that can be adjusted within the IPC/SCTP configuration.  HSRP switches over fast enough.  I just need the VTI to go up/down and reset so it will reestablish the connection and start passing traffic.

Comment: @Cown, we used to do that, but some of the devices simply had unacceptable CPU levels that were affecting other things (VoIP phones were resetting, etc.).

Comment: @KyleRogers, then you should also have a link between the two routers, and you should track the interfaces so that you can failover when the link goes down, but the router is still up. That will let traffic still flow in that situation while the FHRP is still failing over. I really do not see the need for HSRP in your diagram because the layer-3 switch can be the gateway. HSRP is on creating a single gateway, and the layer-3 switch can do that.

Comment: In our real solution we do not have a L3 switch there.  Sorry for the confusion.  It is just a Cisco 2960.

Comment: @RonMaupin I updated the post with a screenshot for clarification of the failure and how it proceeds.This is taken from the remote site (r3) perspective.

Comment: "_It is just a Cisco 2960._" OK, but you _could_ configure the 296 as a layer-3 switch. It just needs the IPBase license. In any case, you need to take into account the scenario where the next link on the active router is down, yet the router is still up. That requires a link between the routers and interface tracking configured on the router for HSRP.

Comment: I agree about HSRP tracking needing to be added.  But I'm simply dumping the entire router for now just to keep it simple.  I understand the 2960's can run L3 code, but we don't have that option.  This is apart of CSfC solution that requires specific equipment and code revisions.

Comment: Well, based on what you added to the question (please, never use an image for text), the problem seem to be when an interface goes down. Tracking the interface can failover HSRP much faster than letting it notice a router is completely down. That is because the active router will explicitly tell the standby router that it has reduced its priority, rather than the standby router needing to wait for expiration of timers. In the mean time, the active router can route traffic to the standby router via a link between them to keep traffic flowing.